# reverse order of bytes in NSData

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdata

never did this (except school). so i'm totally on the dark.

i have data (void *) and it's size (UInt32) so i can simply make something like

```
[NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:data length:dataSize freeWhenDone:YES]
```

this to get a NSData instance (which i need), but i want "slice" the this data in 1 or 2 byte blocks and reverse it's order.

a short example would be great.

thx.

Comment: this sounds like an endianness problem, am I right?

Comment: hi Klemens!  could you tick an answer please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you're struggling to find out what the heck is going on in the bytes during development,

```
typedef struct _SliceItUp
    {
    UInt8   a,b,c,d; // 4 x 8bits == 32 bits
    }
    SliceItUp;

SliceItUp dd;

[data getBytes:&dd length:sizeof(SliceItUp)];

NSLog(@"the four friends are %d %d %d %d", dd.a,dd.b,dd.c,dd.d);
```

You now have the four bytes individually as four totally distinct bytes.

You have total control and you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for the functions defined in NSByteOrder.h